# In Swift,there's no way to get the returned function's argument names?

Tags: swift, function, return, swift3

When a function's return value is another function,there's no way to get the returned function's argument names.Is this a pitfall of swift language?

For example:

```
func makeTownGrand(budget:Int,condition: (Int)->Bool) -> ((Int,Int)->Int)?
{
    guard condition(budget) else {
        return nil;
    }

    func buildRoads(lightsToAdd: Int, toLights: Int) -> Int
    {
        return toLights+lightsToAdd
    }

    return buildRoads
}

func evaluateBudget(budget:Int) -> Bool
{
    return budget > 10000
}

var stopLights = 0

if let townPlan = makeTownGrand(budget: 30000, condition: evaluateBudget)
{
    stopLights = townPlan(3, 8)
}
```

Be mindful of `townPlan`,`townPlan(lightsToAdd: 3, toLights: 8)` would be much more sensible to `townPlan(3, 8)`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. From the Swift 3 release notes:

> Argument labels have been removed from Swift function types... Unapplied references to functions or initializers no longer carry argument labels.

Thus, the type of `townPlan`, i.e. the type returned from calling `makeTownGrand`, is `(Int,Int) -> Int` — and carries no external argument label information.

For a full discussion of the rationale, see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/545e7bea606f87a7ff4decf656954b0219e037d3/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md