# Expected type after conversion to swift 3 in closure

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I have the following method in my class:

```
func save(item: ProductInstanceModel, mileageLocalId: Int, callback: (result: NSDictionary?) -> Void) {

   //...

   callback(result: someResult)

   //...

}
```

After I converted my code to Swift 3 through the Xcode wizard I get:

```
Function type cannot have argument label 'result'; use '_' instead
```

And when I rename it to _ I get:

```
(_ result: NSDictionary?) -> Void

Expected type
```

I reviewed the documentation and found nothing about changes in closures in regards to parameters. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I rename it to _ I get"? Do you mean `callback: (_ result: NSDictionary?) -> Void`?

Comment: Huh, it compiles fine for me (although note you'll have to invoke the callback as `callback(someResult)`). Have you tried cleaning your build folder? If that doesn't work, could you please show the entire function signature after you've made the change? Regarding the rationale of the change itself, see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577598/in-swift-theres-no-way-to-get-the-returned-functions-argument-names).