# How can I have label for my closure parameter in swift?

Tags: swift

This is my Closure with this code:

```
let myWorkClosure: (String) -> Void = { value in
    print(value)
}
```

and use case of:

```
myWorkClosure("Hello, world!")
```

How can I have a label for that like this:

```
myWorkClosure(value: "Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Anonymous function parameter labels were abolished starting in Swift 3:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md

All you can do is make a type alias for your closure's function type, and document the purpose of the parameter. In your type alias, the parameter can have an "inner" label (a local label); this makes no difference to the code ultimately, but it least it gives you a documentable name. Example:

```
/// My cool closure type
/// - Parameter value: The value.
typealias MyWorkClosureType = (_ value: String) -> Void
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578005/9223839 :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yeah, go ahead, make me feel old!!!! I couldn't find it because the search terms are so different from this one! OTOH my answer here is a bit more helpful, it's updated, etc. So not truly duplication. In fact I'm going to suggest you might want to undo your dupehammer.